# Is there a magma with this property?

Tags: universal-algebra, magma

Does there exist a magma $(S,*)$ such that the only quasi-identities that $*$ satisfies are the trivial ones? And if so, can someone give me an explicit example of such a magma?

Comment: I guess a *free* magma over any set would do the job.

Comment: In a free magma, the quasi-identity $ab=ac \implies b=c$ holds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any quasi-identity only involves finitely many elements of a magma, so if it fails to hold identically it fails to hold in some finitely generated magma. So we can take e.g. the free product of all finitely generated magmas (there are uncountably many of these) or the free product of one counterexample for each quasi-identity (there are countably many of these).

Comment: This answer is correct, but it can be improved. Firstly, each universal sentence $\sigma$ which fails in a magma $M$ with respect to some interpretation $v$ fails in a finite magma: only finitely many elements of $M$ (forming a set $X \subseteq M$) occur as interpretations with respect to $v$ of subterms of terms which occur in $\sigma$, and the multiplication on $X$ can be redefined arbitrarily whenever a product of two elements of $X$ lies outside of $X$ in $M$.

Comment: Secondly, instead of the free product, one can take a union (and define multiplication between components arbitrarily). Thus, a more economic construction is to take any magma defined on the union of all finite magmas where multiplication on the union extends multiplication on the components.